# Event not firing - Alchemy Polygon Mumbai API difference to Alchemy Eth Ropsten API?

Tags: ropsten, polygon

I have a simple smart contract deployed via Hardhat to both Eth Ropsten and Polygon Mumbai testnets. It contains a function that my app calls, and the function fires an event as below.

```
   event ReturnQueue(
     Message[] queue
   );

   function add(string memory id, address[] memory recipients, uint channelId, string memory content, uint networkId) public {
      queue.push(Message(id, block.timestamp, block.number, tx.gasprice, msg.sender, recipients, channelId, content, networkId));
      emit ReturnQueue(queue);
   }
```

My app is setup using Ethers.js to listen for the event via Alchemy API.

```
this.mumbaiContract.contract = new this.$ethers.Contract(this.mumbaiContract.address, this.iacontractabi, this.mumbaiContract.signer);

this.ropstenContract.contract = new this.$ethers.Contract(this.ropstenContract.address, this.iacontractabi, this.ropstenContract.signer);

this.ropstenContract.contract.on("ReturnQueue", (queue, event) => {
      console.log('Ropsten event ReturnQueue watch: ');
      console.log(queue);
    });

    this.mumbaiContract.contract.on("ReturnQueue", (queue, event) => {
console.log('Mumbai event ReturnQueue watch: ');
      console.log(queue);
    });
```

For both .on listeners I can see constant POST calls to the Alchemy API checking for a new event.

The problem is that the Polygon Mumbai one never receives an event response, whereas the Eth Ropsten does.

Any thoughts?

Comment: A common reason for this error could be the wrong RPC URL. Have you double-checked if you are using the URL with the right key?

Comment: Yep the API URL and the API KEY are correct. I'm submitting a call to function add via the alchemy API and also listening on it - I get a successful transaction when calling add but the event listener doesnt pick up the ReturnQueue event like it does (almost immediately) on ropsten.

Comment: Does switching the order of the two event listeners change anything?

Answer (score 0):

You need to paginate the events:

> You can make eth_getLogs requests with up to a 2K block range and
> 150MB limit on the response size. You can also request any block range
> with a cap of 10K logs in the response.

Source: https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/guides/eth_getlogs